# I cannot install the dotnet-sdk-8.0.203-win-x64 version

Tags: .net, windows, sdk

When i try to install the sdk i keep getting this error :[link to image with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/po1pL.png)

In cmd I already have installed the sdk 7 version , is it causing the problems?[link to images with cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZRRG.png)

I tried finding that files but it seems to be missing, [link to image folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbxS7.png)
Should i delete the 8.0.3 folder and try to install it again?

Also i try to install that cause I use Godot engine and one of the plugins requires the newer version of .net pack. Any help appreciated

Comment: Have tried running the installer as admin?

Comment: Tried that, same thing happens

Comment: That looks like a more general IO error rather than something .net related. If you are running any kind of third party antivirus/malware software try disabling it.